# CSS - Font being blocked from Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Policy

Tags: css

On my website https://www.stubwire.com when people start an order process I am loading the CSS file from https://files.stubwire.com. The problem is that the CSS file is trying to load the font giving the error. Can someone help show me how to fix this issue? My fixes I have seen talk about using Amazon S3 but this is loading from our own servers.

**Error**

*Font from origin 'https://files.stubwire.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.stubwire.com' is therefore not allowed access.*

**CSS Code**
Source: https://files.stubwire.com/static/stubwire_v3/style.css?date=20141213

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSansRegular';
    src: url('fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/DroidSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/DroidSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/DroidSans-webfont.svg#DroidSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: You could inline the font in your css or use a different font, like verdana.

Comment: You just need to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your resource response

Comment: Like this: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.foo.com` Example from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you control the server, then you can adjust the settings of your server Apache/Nginx or whatever to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to your HTTP responses.

In your case, you probably want something like (this will allow your domain to access the fonts, but prevent other domains from using it, including your own subdomains):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.stubwire.com
```

I got the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header usage from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Here is another resource that gives examples of how to set up various servers (IIS, Nginx, Apache) to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header: https://support.maxcdn.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036555812

Comment: New URL: https://www.maxcdn.com/one/tutorial/how-to-use-cdn-with-webfonts/

Answer (score 22):

If you don't have `mod_headers` enabled you can enabled it with

`sudo a2enmod headers`

And then in your `VirtualHost` or `.htaccess`

```
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, this code worked perfectly. make sure you change your domain.

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```

Answer (score -15):

In your CSS where you are loading the font instead of an HTTP response, turn it into HTTPS.

For instance, in the code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'DroidSansRegular';
src: url('http://...fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/DroidSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/DroidSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/DroidSans-webfont.svg#DroidSansRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Make it:

```
src: url('https://...fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot');
```

Do this with all your fonts.