# Wordpress: CORS - Icons are not showing in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, cors, cdn

I have been fighting with this problem since some weeks, and after all the researches...., I think I need your help.

It's about my website: [shoother.net](http://www.shoother.net)

It seems to work fine with Safari, but if you use Firefox and Chrome, the icons wont show up. Just scroll down the home page until the last section "Get Connected" or in the about or contact-page.

The problem started while I was trying to solve CDN issues. I wanted to make my pictures load faster, and moved `wp-content/upload`-content in the main root. Everything worked perfectly first (I even minified the JavaScript files), but then the icons won't load anymore.

I wrote to the theme-support about it, and they told me that I need to enable CORS with some codes (putting it in `.htaccess`).

I tried a lot to solve this problem. Chrome always responds with

"Font from origin 'http://content.shoother.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xxxxxxx' is therefore not allowed access."

.... I really hope you guys can help me.
Regards,
Natts

Comment: I seem to have no problems viewing the icons. I am using Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m. I see 5 icons in the get connected section. Facebook Twitter, Instagram, Flickr and Google+

Comment: really? have you seen this "Font from origin 'http://content.shoother.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xxxxxxx' is therefore not allowed access." with the chrome console?

that's wierd. I can't see all the icons, even after I refresh everything + empty all the caches..

Comment: http://imgur.com/IzhNk2D viewing the chrome console shows nothing weird. none of what you describe.

Comment: thats crazy. is my browser joking me? thank you so much. let's see what other people are saying. but I am quite happy about your comment, now. thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Font being blocked from Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726802/css-font-being-blocked-from-cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy)