# @font-face not loading at first time , after click any link font is change why?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

This is how I embed a font:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'fc_lamoonregular';
src: url('../font/fc_lamoon_regular_ver_1.00-webfont.eot');
src: url('../font/fc_lamoon_regular_ver_1.00-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../font/fc_lamoon_regular_ver_1.00-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('../font/fc_lamoon_regular_ver_1.00-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../font/fc_lamoon_regular_ver_1.00-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../font/fc_lamoon_regular_ver_1.00-webfont.svg#fc_lamoonregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

The first time I navigate to http://www.muangkaen.go.th/index.php , it doesn't matter what link I click on the font is always normal. Will someone tell me why and help me understand the problem?

This error in Google Chrome inspect please help me.
[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726802/css-font-being-blocked-from-cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy) Solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS - Font being blocked from Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726802/css-font-being-blocked-from-cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy)